# Read data from redis queue only when it contains any data

Tags: java, redis, stream, queue, streaming

I have a redis queue let's say "TestQueue".

Currently, I am continuously popping from `queue` without considering if `queue` contains data or not as according to my below code.

```
private void startStreaming() {
        JedisConnectionManager redis = new JedisConnectionManager();
        Jedis jedis = redis.getJedisConnection();
        while (true) {
            List<String> redisData = jedis.brpop(0, new Constants().getRedisBackupQueue());
            String query = redisData.get(1);

            LOGGER.info("data received from redis backup queue: " + query);
            writeToCassandra(query);
        }
    }
```

What I want to accomplish is, instead of continuously popping, I want to only pop when queue contain some data (e.g some kind of producer-consumer problem).

How can I better impliment my above code for my use case.

Comment: `brpop(0, …)` keeps the connection blocked for possibly ever. You can invert your logic and take advantage of Keyspace Notifications, listen via Pub/Sub whenever a message is inserted into the queue. `BRPOP` polling isn't too bad either but you should set a short interval (< 30 seconds) to minimize the chance the connection gets closed by some network component due to inactivity.

Comment: publish-subscribe have a little problem according to my use case.

What if I missed listening some message. I will forever loose it.

Comment: The above code **does not** continuously pop - it waits patiently until there's something in the list. Read the documentation.

Comment: yes by using `brpop` it waits till it get some data. Thanks for clearing it out.